Ionic backbutton changes the URL but does not load the component
I encountered the following error when trying to navigate using the back button:

The browser's address bar updates with the new URL, but the component does not render. Could you please advise on what might be causing this issue?
There is my code
BaseLayout
<template>
  <ion-menu content-id="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu list</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">This is the menu content.</ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-page id="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons>
          <ion-back-button
            :default-href="pageDefaultBackLink"
          ></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{ pageTitle }}</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons>
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title></ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="parention-padding">
      <slot />
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonMenu,
  IonMenuButton,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonButton,
  IonButtons,
  IonBackButton,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonHeader,
    IonMenu,
    IonMenuButton,
    IonPage,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonButton,
    IonButtons,
    IonBackButton,
  },
  props: {
    pageTitle: String,
    pageDefaultBackLink: String,
  },
});
</script>


MainPage
<template>
  <BaseLayout page-title="Main page">
    <ion-content class="parention-padding">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="top-element">
          <ion-button router-link="/serverlist">Default</ion-button>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-element">
          <UIconButton icon="power-outline" text="Домой" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </BaseLayout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import UIconButton from "./components/UIconButton.vue";

import {
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
} from "@ionic/vue";

import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {   
    IonContent,
    IonButton,
    UIconButton,
  },
});
</script>

ServerList
<template>
  <BaseLayout page-title="Server list" page-default-back-link="/home">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Pokémon Yellow</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </BaseLayout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonList } from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonList },
});
</script>


I tried switching component loading to Lazy, but it didn't help.
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router';
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/home'
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/MainPage.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/serverlist',
    name: 'ServerList',
    component: () => import('../views/ServerList.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router



Any query selector or alike in the code?

This error means that when going back the previous component is not found and thus making the component visible results in failure due to missing classList.

Also why you have not imported BaseLayout on the main pages?

BaseLayout is imported globally in main.js

Do you have the same error from both the pages or its on specific page?

I have only 2 pages and back button exists only on ServerList component
